# How to sftp connect through Paramiko with public key - python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

i'm using Paramiko to connect through sftp to a server.but i can't understand how to connect with below Putty User key file

Code:

```
       local_path = "C:\blp\aisrvintraday1045.csv"
       remote_path = "/aisrvintraday1045.csv"
       cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts ()
       cnopts.hostkeys.load('C:\Python code\SSH-KEY-08142018(private).ppk')
       with pysftp.Connection (host='sftp.bloomberg.com', username='user', password='pass', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
            sftp.get(local_path, remote_path)
            data = sftp.listdir ()
            for i in data:
               print(i)
            sftp.close()
```

I connect to it with this ppk file:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: rsa-key@20180814
Public-Lines: 12
[12 lines key]
Private-Lines: 28
[28 lines key]
Private-MAC: [hash]
```

Error:

```
   (<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException'>, SSHException('Bad host key 
   from server',), <traceback object at 0x7fa76269c5a8>)
   Bad host key from server
```

I've tried to include that ppk file and set to auth_public_key, but didn't work.

Can you please help me? I am struggling for long time.

Comment: Key pair for authentication has nothing to do with host keys. - See my article on [SSH keys](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys) to understand.